# I am struggling to convert HH:MM time format in excel to numeric minutes in R

Tags: ggplot2, time, lubridate

As a final product, I am trying to plot the differences between two times (calculated as hours:minutes in excel eg. 1:27) as a numeric minute values (y axis) over dates (x axis) but everytime I plot the graphs, it still shows up as the H:Min format. As a result I am unable to put a horizontal "threshold" line on my graph at a certain minute point (45mins)

Here is the code I have so far:

```
Date<- as.Date(Date,format="%m/%d/%y") #to convert the Dates to Date format

#Next converting time to numeric bc it defaults to character (would love if someone could figure out how to do this w tidyverse bc this code is NOT elegant lol):

time<-hm(time)
time<-as.numeric(as.duration(time))

#Convert to minutes
time <- time/60

#graph

ggplot(Sample, aes(x=Date, y=time))+
geom_point()+
theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 45,hjust = 1))+
scale_x_discrete(guide = guide_axis(angle = 60)) +
theme_bw()+
geom_hline(aes(yintercept=45), color='red')
```

This generates a graph with the HH:MM format still on the Y axis and my red line at 45mins nowhere in site.

Thanks so much

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the code above,  it looks like the Sample dataframe is not being modified before it is being used in ggplot. Can you confirm if the Date and time columns in Sample are in the right format by printing or viewing the dataframe?

Comment: Thanks for the response Vishal, I mistakenly omitted that I attached the Sample dataframe after loading the CSV. So Date is confirmed a "Date" and time is "numeric"